# Why Python gets installed in Frameworks directory?

Tags: python, macos

I've been wondering why python gets installed in directory named Frameworks? (though it's not Framework)

```
$ which python                                                                                    
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Somebody please explain! Thanks!

Comment: If the explanation was "That's the way it is in the Mac OS", would you accept it?

Comment: I would still wait to hear from others :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the way it is in OS X.

The [Mac/README file in the Python source tree](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Mac/README?view=markup) goes into some more details of the advantages of a framework build versus a traditional UNIX shared-library build, which will also work on OS X.  The main points:

- "The main reason is because you want
  to create GUI programs in Python.
  With the exception of
  X11/XDarwin-based GUI toolkits all
  GUI programs need to be run  from a
  fullblown MacOSX application (a
  ".app" bundle).

  While it is technically possible to
  create a .app without using
  frameworks you will have to do the
  work yourself if you really want
  this.

  A second reason for using frameworks
  is that they put Python-related items
  in only two places:
  "/Library/Framework/Python.framework"
  and  "/Applications/MacPython 2.6". 
  This simplifies matters for users
  installing  Python from a binary
  distribution if they want to get rid
  of it again. Moreover, due to the way
  frameworks work a user without admin
  privileges can install a  binary
  distribution in his or her home
  directory without recompilation."

Comment: README.txt: `The installer puts the applications in "Python 2.7" 
in your Applications folder, command-line tools in
/usr/local/bin and the underlying machinery in
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework.`

Comment: The second point isn't really true though. For instance the site-packages directory is under /Library/Python/2.6.

Comment: `/Library/Python/` is the default site-packages location for the Apple-supplied Pythons shipped with OS X, not with the python.org installed Pythons nor ones built from source.  Those use `/Library/Frameworks ...`.